# create time bins based on 12 hour format as columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as having column as time_bin which is binning of hours in 12 hours format:

```
df=

 unique_id   time_bin
    s_001    2 AM_5 AM
    s_002    9 PM_11 PM
    s_003    10 AM_6 PM
    s_004    2 PM_7 PM
```

All I want to create a dataframe having 24 columns range from 12 AM to 12 PM like 12 AM_1 AM,1 AM-2 AM,2 AM-3 AM......11 PM-12 PM and raise the flag of columns as '1' which lies in that range of time_bin column and other columns will be '0'. such as:

```
new_df= unique_id   time_bin  12 AM_1 AM 1 AM_2 AM 2 AM-3 AM 3 AM-4 AM.......9 PM_10 PM 10 PM_11 PM 11 PM_12 PM
        s_001       2 AM_5 AM        0         0         1         1               0           0          0  
        s_002       9 PM_11 PM       0         0         0         0               1           1          0   
        s_003       10 AM_6 PM       0         0         0         0               0           0          0  
        s_004       12 AM_7 AM       1         1         1         1               0           0         0   
        .....       ......
        .....       ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from datetime import datetime

def f(x):
    #split values and convert to hours
    s, e = x.split('_')
    s = datetime.strptime(s, '%I %p').hour
    e = datetime.strptime(e, '%I %p').hour
    #convert to Series fileld by 1
    a = pd.Series(1, index=range(s, e + 1))
    return (a)

#replace missing values to 0 and add all missing hours by reindex
df1 = (df['time_bin'].apply(f)
                     .fillna(0)
                     .astype(int)
                     .reindex(columns=range(0, 24), fill_value=0))

#convert back to original format
new = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns, format='%H').strftime('%I %p')
#join by f-strings shifted values
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in zip(new, new[1:].tolist() + ['12 PM'])]

df = df.join(df1)
```

---

```
print (df)
  unique_id    time_bin  12 AM_01 AM  01 AM_02 AM  02 AM_03 AM  03 AM_04 AM  \
0     s_001   2 AM_5 AM            0            0            1            1   
1     s_002  9 PM_11 PM            0            0            0            0   
2     s_003  10 AM_6 PM            0            0            0            0   
3     s_004  12 AM_7 AM            1            1            1            1   

   04 AM_05 AM  05 AM_06 AM  06 AM_07 AM  07 AM_08 AM  ...  02 PM_03 PM  \
0            1            1            0            0  ...            0   
1            0            0            0            0  ...            0   
2            0            0            0            0  ...            1   
3            1            1            1            1  ...            0   

   03 PM_04 PM  04 PM_05 PM  05 PM_06 PM  06 PM_07 PM  07 PM_08 PM  \
0            0            0            0            0            0   
1            0            0            0            0            0   
2            1            1            1            1            0   
3            0            0            0            0            0   

   08 PM_09 PM  09 PM_10 PM  10 PM_11 PM  11 PM_12 PM  
0            0            0            0            0  
1            0            1            1            1  
2            0            0            0            0  
3            0            0            0            0
```